# Eclipse java Press enter key after giving input

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing input in a text box using following code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tocGotoInputBox\"]")).sendKeys(s);
```

After that I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and for that I am using the following code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tocGotoInputBox\"]")).click();
```

But this is not working. Is there any other way to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after giving input in text box?

Comment: We may need to see the html you are working with. (Side note, might be good to create your search string once rather than typing it each time in separate xpath statements)

Comment: Actually the input is coming from sheet so its necessary to type it each time.

Comment: <input type="text" id="InputBox" restrict="0-9" class="goPageInpFld" placeholder="Go to Page">

Comment: What i am using is                                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tocGotoInputBox\"]")).sendKeys(s);                                                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tocGotoInputBox\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);                                                                                                             But this is not working.

Comment: i try the above line of code                                 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tocGotoInputBox\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter‌​);                                          Now its working